# Linked List Hash Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

For LRU-Cache, a `LinkedListHashMap` is a very useful structure.

In Ruby 1.9, Hashes now have

```
Ruby 1.9 internal hash entry struct
struct st_table_entry {
unsigned int hash;
st_data_t key;
st_data_t record;
st_table_entry *next;
st_table_entry *fore, *back; // new in Ruby 1.9
};
```

https://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/

How an I can I use this to set the `next` & `back` properties on an entry ? This will make accessing and inserting into a doubly linked list much simpler !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby 1.9 Hash implementation has no next or back method. Most of the time, if you need such functionality the Hash is converted to an array of tuples, keys or values. But since a Hash is [enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) you can use next on this like below.

```
h = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}

enum  = h.to_enum
enum.next
enum.next
p enum.next # [:three, 3]
p enum.next # error `next': iteration reached an end (StopIteration)

enum  = h.to_enum.cycle
enum.next
enum.next
enum.next
p enum.next # [:one, 1]
enum.rewind
p enum.next # [:one, 1]
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! I had no idea you could convert a data structure to enumerable !

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way us to delete the key and then readd it

```
hash.delete(:some_key)
hash[:some_key] = some_value
```

Then `:some_key` will be shifted to the end of `hash`

Comment: Thanks, I realized this after !